# Risk Ratio proc genmod predictor variable has multiple levels

Tags: sas

I am using `proc genmod` to estimate risk ratios. Two of my predictor variables have more than 2 levels.  My `gender` variable is `‘male’, ‘female’, ‘other’` and race is `‘white’`,`’non-hispanic black’`, `‘hispanic’`.  Here is how I set up the model. I get only 1 risk ratio. Is it possible to risk ratio for each level of the predictor variable?  I have not done this before, so any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Proc genmod data=rr_genmod;
Class gender(ref=’male’) race (ref=’white’);
Model outcomeA(ref=’1’)=gender race/ dist=binomial link=log;
ESTIMATE 'BETA' GENDER 1-1/EXP;
ESTIMATE 'BETA' RACE 1-1/EXP;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the LSMEANS then perhaps LSMESTIMATE for more complex estimates.  The syntax is would be something like this.

```
LSMEANS GENDER RACE / DIFF CL EXP;
```

There are other options that may be useful but you should consult the documentation for those details.